# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, magento

I'm getting this syntax error and I know it's PHP 101, but I wouldn't know php if it hit me over the head with a curly bracket.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<?php echo ($this->getProduct()->getCategory() ? $this->getProduct()->getCategory()->getName() : ‘no category’) ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What kind of apostrophe is that?

```
‘no category’
```

Should be

```
'no category'
```

Comment: Hah! Good catch, thanks. It was originally copypasted from a forum thread, so that's probably where the weird apostrophe came in.

Thanks, that fixed the error :)

Answer (score 2):

; at the end of the statement?

Comment: Thanks, tried that and it didn't work.
@Gumbo Thanks for the tip